# Show several annotations in iOS Map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to show user's current location and users nearby the area.

I am doing to show user's

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location  = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:location!.coordinate.latitude ,longitude :  location!.coordinate.longitude )
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01 )

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Plotting near by users
`plotUsersonGraph(lat,longitude:long,title:"Apple HQ",subtitle:"Welcome to Apple")`

```
func plotUsersonGraph(latitude:Double,longitude:Double,title:String,subtitle:String){
        let HQlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: HQlocation, span: span)
      //  self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)**THIS IS CAUSING PROBLEM**

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = HQlocation

        annotation.title = title
        annotation.subtitle = subtitle
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }
```

I am able to view both the locations individually but I am unable to merge both of them together. `plotUsersonGraph` will add multiple users on the graph simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved it

Added

```
          self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

inside

```
    func plotUsersonGraph(latitude:Double,longitude:Double,title:String,subtitle:String){
}
```